# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError during API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying to set up an API that logs in a user to my application and authenticates the user with  a token. For this I am creating a new session.

Sessions controller

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def create
    user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
    if user&.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render json: user.as_json(only: [:first_name, :last_name, :email]), status: :created
    else
      head(:unauthorized)
    end
  end
```

Base controller

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  include Pundit

  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index

  rescue_from StandardError,                with: :internal_server_error
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError,   with: :user_not_authorized
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

  private

  def internal_server_error(exception)
    if Rails.env.development?
      response = { type: exception.class.to_s, message: exception.message, backtrace: exception.backtrace }
    else
      response = { error: "Internal Server Error" }
    end
    render json: response, status: :internal_server_error
  end

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
    render json: {
      error: "Unauthorized #{exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore.camelize}.#{exception.query}"
    }, status: :unauthorized
  end

  def not_found(exception)
    render json: { error: exception.message }, status: :not_found
  end

end
```

When I test the method, I receive `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`, despite the user existing in the database. It points to the last line of the `internal_server_error(exception)` method of the BaseController.

Can someone help me understand why this code doesn't render the JSON of the user, when the user actually does exist in the database?

Comment: Thats not a good way to customize the error responses. Instead you want to set `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` and create a `get '/500'` route. "catch-all" error handling should be done on the framework level and not in your base controller is it won't catch errors that happen before the controller like in the routes or middleware. https://anoobbava.github.io/blog/2018/03/22/create-custom-error-pages-in-rails/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't see how it directly relates to my question though?

Comment: The thing is that you can solve the immediate problem but what this error is telling you is that your approach is broken. You have a catch-all that is basically swallowing some kind of exception but not halting execution so that render is being called twice. You can either spend time putting makeup on a pig or actually fixing the root cause.

Comment: So you mean that the line `rescue_from StandardError, with: :internal_server_error` swallows an exception? Is there a way to see which exception is being thrown or would I create different routes for the most common errors as per the link you provided? If you remove `render json: response, status: :internal_server_error` the code actually works but then again that's probably what you meant with putting makeup on a pig.